# Vertical alignment in tables without multirow

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}| p{8cm} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}
\hline
ONE & Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.  & 100\\
\hline
TWO & \lipsum[1] & 200\\
\hline
THREE & \lipsum[2] & 300\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and displayed

[image]

That I want, only first and third column vertical alignment. Also it is changing vertical length in first and third column its lines.

I did found like answers of another questions. But I don't working in full my code. Is it possible especially without **multirow**?

Comment: change the middle column to `m` from `p`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't believe this, perfect working. I am ashamed.

Comment: I'm not sure that middle alignment is typographically sound, but it's just an opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the vertical alignment with `m` in the middle column

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8cm}|
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|}
```

but the table is too wide for `article` a4 text width

```
Overfull \hbox (47.48578pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--16
```

Perhaps

```
\begin{tabular}{|c| m{8cm} |c|}
```

[image]